# how to scroll to first view from last in uiscrollview

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiscrollview, swift2

I have created three views under a scrollview viz. V1, V2 and V3. I want to scroll from V3 to V1 and vice versa. How do I do it? My code is as follows.

```
let V1 : View1 = View1 (nibName: "View1", bundle: nil)
let V2 : View2 = View2 (nibName: "View2", bundle: nil)
let V3 : View3 = View3 (nibName: "View3", bundle: nil)

self.addChildViewController(V1)
self.scroll1.addSubview(V1.view)
V1.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

self.addChildViewController(V2)
self.scroll1.addSubview(V2.view)
V2.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

self.addChildViewController(V3)
self.scroll1.addSubview(V3.view)
V3.didMoveToParentViewController(self)


var V2Frame : CGRect = V2.view.frame
V2Frame.origin.x=self.view.frame.width
V2.view.frame = V2Frame

var V3Frame : CGRect = V3.view.frame
V3Frame.origin.x = 2 * self.view.frame.width
V3.view.frame = V3Frame


self.scroll1.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.width * 3, self.view.frame.size.height)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply apply animation on `contentOffset` of your `UIScrollView`

```
    func animateScrollViewTo(point:CGPoint){
      UIView.animateWithDuration(0.25) { () -> Void in
        self.scrollView.contentOffset = point
      }
    }
```

After that whenever you need to scroll simply call above function like:

```
self.animateScrollViewTo(self.V1.frame.origin)
```

or you can directly call the point you want to scroll like this

```
self.animateScrollViewTo(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
```

Comment: It's not working. I'm not able to scroll from the last view i.e. V3 back to V1.